# Discord js v12 Send message if someone reacts to embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm currently making a discord bot using discord.js v12 (yes 12 not 13), I made a command that the bot sends an embed and reacts to it, in the filter I set the max to 2 (max: 2, ...). I want that every time someone reacts with this embed that like his name will be send in the channel. My current concept is this(it's in a function because I don't want to but everything in the switch):

```
async function fun_2p() {
  const reactionMessage2p = await message.channel.send(embed2p);
  const filter2p = (reaction, user) => user.id !== bot;

  await reactionMessage2p.react('')

  reactionMessage2p.awaitReactions( filter2p, {max: 2, time: 20000, errors: ['time'] }).then(collected => {
                    
  })
}
```

Right before the last `})` should be the code for the answer (I guess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Message#createReactionCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) instead, and listen for the [`collect`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector?scrollTo=e-collect) event

```js
const reactionMessage2p = await message.channel.send(embed2p);
const filter2p = (reaction, user) => user.id !== bot

await reactionMessage2p.react('')

const collector = reactionMessage2p.createReactionCollector(filter2p, {max: 2, time: 20000, errors: ['time'] })

collector.on("collect", (reaction, user) => {
  reaction.message.channel.send(`${user.tag} has just reacted to the message`)
})
```

You can change the message to whatever you want

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but it's not working for me :/

Comment: How? Are you getting an error? Is it not doing *anything*?

Comment: No I don't get an error, nothing. No message in the chat and no console log.

Comment: Ah I found the error, it's: `const collector = reactionMessage2p.createReactionCollector`... and not `const collector = message.createReactionCollector` ...
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: If my answer helped, consider giving it a checkmark

Comment: I will do that :) Maybe change the `message` to `reactionMessage2p`, so it's 100% right. Thanks

Comment: Oh I thought I made it that before