# Discord js v12 Add rights to a channel if user reacts to a specific message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a problem that I can't solve:
Every time someone reacts to a specific message a channel gets created, and then the person who reacted first is the only one who has the permissions to see this channel. I set the max amount of reactions to "2", and I want it so that the second person who reacts with the message also gets permissions to see the created channel, but I don't know how to do it. Does somebody has an example?
This is what I currently have:

```
 message.guild.channels.create("Busfahrer", {
                    type: "text",
                    parent: category,
                    permissionOverwrites: [
                        {
                            id: message.guild.id,
                            allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'EMBED_LINKS', 'ATTACH_FILES', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY'],
                            deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],                                
                        }
                    ]
                })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of who reacts first and second and only give it to the second person:

```js
const collector = reactionMessage2p.createReactionCollector(filter2p, {max: 2, time: 20000, errors: ['time'] })
let reactedUsers = []

collector.on("collect", (reaction, user) => {
  reactedUsers.push(user.id)
})

collector.on("end", async () => {
  let targetUser = reactedUsers[1]
  // channel is the channel you create
  channel.updateOverwrite(targetUser, {
    VIEW_CHANNEL: true
  })
})
```

I got some of this code from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70189230/discord-js-v12-send-message-if-someone-reacts-to-embed)

Comment: Hm, seems good, but I have currently all the time the error code: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'updateOverwrite'). I don't know why or what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: When creating the channel, be sure to do `let channel = await message.guild.channels.create(...)`

Comment: I tried it but it still does not work. But I saw that when the second person reacts a new channel will be created also, so I have to find a way to stop this too.

Comment: Do this: `if (!reactedUsers.length) { // channel create code}`, and as for the other part, make a variable called `channel` outside the callbacks, but inside the function and do `channel = await message.guild.channels.create(...)` as the channel create code

Comment: Ahh now the second person gets the permissions also, nice. But if I use `if (!reactedUser.length) ...` and then react, no channel will be created and I get the error message again: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'updateOverwrite')

Comment: Hmm... try logging `reactedUser` on each collect event and tell me what it logs. Also, did you mean to add an s at the end?

Comment: It logs `reactedUsers` only onces, at the beginning at: `let reactedUsers = []`. As soon as the 2nd person reacts it logs both ID's two times until collector "end", then it failes. And I didn't miss a s. :)

Comment: So it doesn't log on the first time?

Comment: No it logs on the first time, it failes at the last log. `collector.on("end", async () => {
  let targetUser = reactedUsers[1]
console.log(reactedUsers)
  // channel is the channel you create
  channel.updateOverwrite(targetUser, {
    VIEW_CHANNEL: true
  })
})`

Comment: Maybe you can post a pastebin link here with all your code? What I have from the comments right now is not really enough for me to help you debug

Comment: https://srcb.in/9eo3AMhfsQ Sure :)

Comment: Above, on the outside of the `collector.on("collect"` put `let channel;`

Comment: you mean: `let channel = await message.guild.channels.create(`Busfahrer ` + counter, ...` ? or just `let channel;`?

Comment: Oh yeah, I see in the console that it gives me 2 Outputs for the 2 channels its creating

Comment: Got it! It has to be `if (reactedUsers.length === 1) ...`

Comment: So does it work now?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help.

Comment: I understand why you needed that: you were pushing *before* the check